# Make Apache (Mac) recognize proper Python location

Tags: python, macos, apache

I'm having the following issue. I have a build of python installed at /usr/local/bin/python. I have some CGI scripts that I'm tinkering around with. During testing I've run these scripts from the command line, and then I use them for some AJAX coordination. I've come to understand that when I run them from the command-line they use a completely different build of python from the one that apache uses when the scripts are invoked by the browser. Here's my sample:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
import os

print(sys.version) 
print('')
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

Run from the command-line, this outputs:

```
2.7.6 (default, Apr  6 2014, 23:14:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)]

/usr/local/opt/python/bin
```

However, loading this url in my browser localhost/cgi-bin/mycoolscript.py outputs:

```
2.7.6 (default, Apr  6 2014, 23:14:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)]

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Gaaa!! A different location for python- no wonder my libraries weren't loading. I've been trying to solve this thing. I have this line in my ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

but that has no bearing on apache. I've looked in my /etc/apache/httpd.conf file and commented out mod_wsgi and mod_python for good measure and restarted apache. No change. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: did you restart  your terminal?

Comment: I'm just wondering why do you run Apache on localhost.

Comment: It's handy to run it on localhost. Macs have apache built in.

Comment: I know Apache is preinstalled there, but I dont see any advantage of using it for development. The performance of CGI scripts is much worse than running scripts via mod_wsgi and every modern framework (Flask, Django...) has bundled its own server which is specially designed for developement (better debugging, reloading scripts after changes etc.)

Comment: I'm also not sure if it's really handy - apparently it causes you some problems you wont have if you wont use it .)

Comment: Well- see, it's really just for me to learn python. I'm a two-day-old python programmer. I haven't set up mod_wsgi yet. And I can't mess around with this stuff on my shared hosting environment- not enough access.

Comment: Avoid mod_cgi or mod_python - they're deprecated, slow and maybe also unsecure. If you want to learn Python, start with Python itself - configuring webserver is not something you need right now and it put another level of complexity and possible source of problems into the development. Look for example on tutorial of Flask: there's an example of simple web application you can run in a minute without configuring server http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/